# How to specify an Order or Sort using the C# driver for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a collection of documents server side by telling the C# driver what the sort order is, but it appears not to support that construct yet.

Is it possible to do this any other way?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can also do it using the SetSortOrder method on the MongoCursor class:

```
db["collection"].Find().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("SortByMe"));
```

Comment: This is a far more "C#" answer than the accept answer. (Here's the relevant documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Modifyingacursorbeforeenumeratingit).

Answer (score 42):

For async methods:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("time");
collection.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>()
{
    Sort = sort
});
```

Comment: Good day, is this possible not in asynchronous way?

Comment: @AljohnYamaro, yes. See above.

Comment: I know you're not supposed just comment "thanks", but I searched forever for this answer. MongoDB .net driver documentation is practically non existent. Thank you!!

Answer (score 35):

Just to add to Chris's answer, in C# Driver 2.x it is now done with `SortBy`, `SortByDescending`, `ThenBy` & `ThenByDescending`

```
collection.Find(bson => true).SortBy(bson => bson["SortByMeAscending"]).ThenByDescending(bson => bson["ThenByMeDescending"]).ToListAsync()
```

Now it resembles Linq even more.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/#sort

Comment: This is what I needed

Comment: This was useful one more time!

Answer (score 29):

Simple usage of api in MongoDB.Driver 2.5.0

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

var database = client.GetDatabase("Blog");

var list = database.GetCollection<BlogPost>("BlogPost")
    .Find(e => e.Deleted == false)
    .SortByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn)
    .Limit(20)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that to sort on multiple fields use this:

```
db["collection"].Find().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("SortByMe").Descending("An‌​dByMe");
```

Answer (score 10):

You can apply sort with `SortDefinition` like this:

```
FilterDefinition<User> filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(a => a.Deleted , false);
SortDefinition<User> sort = Builders<User>.Sort.Descending(a => a.Id);
List<User> result = _dbContext.Users.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(10).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the correct way to do this for FindAsync? It seems .Sort isn't supported on the async methods

Comment: @dks209, Check out this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736413/7657155

Comment: I don't know how I never found that thread! You're my hero!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use linq:

From the documentation: (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)

```
var query=
    (from c in collection.AsQueryable<C>()
    orderby c.X
    select c)

foreach (var d in query)
{
    // process your documents
}
```

If you want you can also limit the results:

```
var query=
    (from c in collection.AsQueryable<C>()
    orderby c.X descending
    select c).Take(1);
```

Just remember to have an index on the field you are sorting by : ]

Answer (score 6):

It seems the way to do this using the existing C# driver is as follows:

```
db["collection"].Find(new Document().Append("query", 
new Document()).Append("orderby", 
new Document().Append(name:1).Append(age,-1)));
```

Which I was turned on to by Sam Corder [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-csharp/browse_thread/thread/b5ffb4c5430e18b9)

Comment: See @Chris Brook's answer for a more C#-ish approach.

Comment: Personally a fan of the mongodb-ish approach

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to the newer style which wasn't available at the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

@DmitryZyr's answer for FindAsync was not working. This one did however.

```
var sortDefinition = new SortDefinitionBuilder<ImmutableLog>().Descending("date");
var findOptions = new FindOptions<ImmutableLog>() {Sort = sortDefinition};
await this.Collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument(), findOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using the API version MongoDB.Driver 2.8.1.
Here is my method that I call to return a list of objects with Descending sorting, if it is required:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetDocumentsForCollection(
        IMongoDatabase database,
        string collectionName,
        FilterDefinition<TEntity> query,
        string databaseCollectionKeyToSortOnDescending)
    {
        var _mongoSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings();
        _mongoSettings.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
        var _collection = database.GetCollection<TEntity>(collectionName, _mongoSettings);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseCollectionKeyToSortOnDescending))
        {
            return _collection.Find(query).ToList();
        }

        return _collection.Find<TEntity>(query).Sort(Builders<TEntity>.Sort.Descending(databaseCollectionKeyToSortOnDescending)).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing this in JavaScript since I don't know C#, but it should have equivalent syntax with the C# driver.

If your query looked like:

```
db.c.find({"foo" : "bar"})
```

and you want to sort by "baz" ascending, wrap your query in a "query" field and add an "orderby" field:

```
db.c.find({"query" : {"foo" : "bar"}, "orderby" : {"baz" : 1}})
```

For descending sort, use -1.