# Dynamic Linq ordering not sorting correctly on certain properties

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, dynamicquery

I have a method to apply some dynamic ordering to an IQueryable. Here is the relevant code:

```
if (orderBy != 0)
{
    if (thenBy != 0 && thenBy != orderBy)
    {
        results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC, " + request.ThenBy + " ASC");
    }
    else if (thenByDesc != 0 && thenByDesc != orderBy)
    {
        results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC, " + request.ThenByDesc + " DESC");
    }
    else
    {
        results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC");
    }
}
```

The problem is the ordering doesn't seem to be working correctly. By example, ordering by the property "Name" which is just a string, doesn't even seem to work.

A fix I did find was to `toList()` the results before applying the ordering, like so:

```
orderedResults = results.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

and then do the OrderBy on the `orderedResults` variable. This would be fine but the results that I am ordering can potentially contain 1000's of items. The performance in this case is quite bad. Is there another solution without bringing the collection into memory?

**UPDATE**

In hindsight, the code I posted isn't clear. Here is the entire method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Order<TSource, TOrdering>(this IQueryable<TSource> results, RequestBase<TOrdering> request)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(TOrdering);
        if (!genericType.IsEnum) return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)results;

        var orderBy = Convert.ToInt32(request.OrderBy as Enum);
        var orderByDesc = Convert.ToInt32(request.OrderByDesc as Enum);
        var thenBy = Convert.ToInt32(request.ThenBy as Enum);
        var thenByDesc = Convert.ToInt32(request.ThenByDesc as Enum);

        if (orderBy != 0)
        {
            if (thenBy != 0 && thenBy != orderBy)
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC, " + request.ThenBy + " ASC");
            }
            else if (thenByDesc != 0 && thenByDesc != orderBy)
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC, " + request.ThenByDesc + " DESC");
            }
            else
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderBy + " ASC");
            }
        }
        else if (orderByDesc != 0)
        {
            if (thenBy != 0 && thenBy != orderByDesc)
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderByDesc + " DESC, " + request.ThenBy + " ASC");
            }
            else if (thenByDesc != 0 && thenByDesc != orderByDesc)
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderByDesc + " DESC, " + request.ThenByDesc + " DESC");
            }
            else
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(request.OrderByDesc + " DESC");
            }
        }

        return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)results;
    }
```

`request.OrderBy` and the other ordering properties are enums. This enum can have values such as 'Name', 'SubmittedDate', etc. on which to order `results` by. This is how I call the method:

`reportsResponses = reportsResponses.Order(request);`

**UPDATE 2**

Further information about the code. I mentioned that the ordering works if I first do this before applying any ordering:

`results = results.ToList().AsQueryable();`

Prior to this, the results are calculated from a mongo driver. We're obtaining the results by querying a mongodb. Is mongo the weak link here?

Comment: What is the type of `results`?

Comment: results is a parameter defined as `this IQueryable<TSource> results`

Comment: And how are you passing a string to `OrderBy`? As is this code will not compile.

Comment: I'll say that probably the problem is in the remaining part of your code... I see even various if conditions...

Comment: I'll post the entire method and try to explain it

Comment: And how are you passing a string to `OrderBy`? As is this code will not compile.

Comment: @Aron I'm not sure what you mean. You mean the `request.OrderBy` variable? Its just an Enum. So if the selected Enum is "Name", the orderBy would look like this: `results = results.OrderBy("Name ASC");`

Comment: `Queryable.OrderBy` does not take a string as an argument. Without knowing what you are using I can't look up the source code, but I suspect you are using this completely wrong.

Comment: @Anon I'm using `System.Linq.Dynamic` which has an OrderBy method which takes a string

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man What is the `enum` you are using?

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: Also, to debug, take the Dynamic Linq out of the equation.  Can you do an orderby with a strongly typed lambda expression and it works?  If not,  mongodb may not be handling the orderby properly.

Comment: @xanatos It's a custom enum called `ReportOrder`. It contains a lot of items to order the results by, including Name, SubmittedDate etc. They do match the exact properties that would be found in the collection, if you are thinking it can't match the string to the property to order. I must stress that this does compile and does work if I `toList()` the results collection first.

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man I do hope you gave the first element the `Name **= 1**`, otherwise its value is `0`

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the MongoDB handling.  Other questions imply it may take some fiddling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123529/how-to-specify-an-order-or-sort-using-the-c-sharp-driver-for-mongodb

Comment: @MarkPeters Yeah I think it is MongoDB. I tried a strongly typed ordering like so: `reportsResponses = reportsResponses.OrderBy(x => x.ReportName);` and it doesn't work. Thank you for the link. I'll check it out

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man, did you figure this out?

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man, Well, we know that the MongoDB linq provider supports sorting. What is the "order" you are doing things in? And what is the other code around this doing? Can you enable profiling on the server and see what query is getting generated? (db.setProfilingLevel(2); Then you look in the db.system.profile collection for the query).