# sort data displayed in table with c# and mongodb

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have to implement a function to sort the data displayed in frontend table. There the user can click the up and down arrow in the relevant column he wants to sort. then all the data in all the columns should be sorted according to that relevant column user clicked. How can i do this in c# with mongodb.

I have wrote this to sort according to the date (one column in the table. There are so many others like name, id etc.)

```
result = await _mongoDb.GetCollection<Entity.Mongo.MyModelClassName>(MyCollectionName)
.Sort(Builder<Entity.Mongo.MyModelClassName>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.Date))
```

this is working fine.

But what i need now is to remove this hard coded one and sort according to the user preference.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should do a simple query and according to the sortOrder selected by the user, server-side you execute the sorting.

This should help you understand this concept : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

So,

1. In the URL, you should have a parameter for the sortOrder.
2. In the OnGet() execute your query and then the sorting on this collection based on this parameter.
3. Then you should have a sorted collection and be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much @Julien Turcotte. this is very useful.

Comment: Julien do you have any idea how to use SortDefinition class in mongodb to do this?

Comment: @Nirdha Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123529/how-to-specify-an-order-or-sort-using-the-c-sharp-driver-for-mongodb